# Solidus ShippingCalculator Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solidus

I am customizing my Solidus project to access Correios' API (Correios is mail and delivery in Brazil) to calculate the shipping, but an error is happen.

I am using gem 'correios-frete'.
When I run in command line a ruby file (correios.rb listen bellow) there is no problem.

```
# correios.rb
require 'correios-frete'
require 'pry-byebug'

frete = Correios::Frete::Calculador.new :cep_origem => "22790-671",
                                        :cep_destino => "06783-090",
                                        :peso => 7.3,
                                        :comprimento => 30,
                                        :largura => 20,
                                        :altura => 35

servicos = frete.calcular :sedex, :pac

binding.pry
puts servicos
```

But when I insert the integration lines in the right file in the project:

```
# app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/correios_api.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

# require 'correios-frete'
require_dependency 'spree/calculator'
require_dependency 'spree/shipping_calculator'

module Spree
  module Calculator::Shipping
    class CorreiosApi < ShippingCalculator
      preference :api_key, :string

      def compute_package(_package)
        binding.pry
        calcula

        9090.90
      end

      def self.description
        "Correios API"
      end


      def calcula
        binding.pry
        frete = Correios::Frete::Calculador.new :cep_origem => "22790-671",
                                                :cep_destino => "06783-090",
                                                :peso => 7.3,
                                                :comprimento => 30,
                                                :largura => 20,
                                                :altura => 35

        servicos = frete.calcular :sedex, :pac
        binding.pry
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Raise this error:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant Spree::Calculator::Shipping::CorreiosApi::Correios:
  app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/correios_api.rb:26:in `calcula'
  app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/correios_api.rb:14:in `compute_package'
```

This error raise at line bellow:

```
frete = Correios::Frete::Calculador.new :cep_origem => "22790-671",
                                        :cep_destino => "06783-090",
                                        :peso => 7.3,
                                        :comprimento => 30,
                                        :largura => 20,
                                        :altura => 35
```

Answer (score 1):

Idiot question... I installed gem BUT, I did not restart rails server :-o